# RegEx How to Find Two Words Near Each Other (with reverse order)

Tags: python, regex

I'm using

\b(small|medium|large)(?:\W+\w+){1,6}?\W+(cheese|pepperoni|sausage)\b

Found here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/near.html

But I'd like to know if there is a way to use reverse order (finds any of the words regardless of order)

Comment: Please show some examples of strings that should match and strings which should not be matched.

Comment: You caould use alternative patterns with `|` , or use multiple look-aheads.

Comment: Example matches: Large pizza with Pepperoni or Pepperoni pizza size Large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can include a maximum of 25 characters before and after the pattern looking for the first 3 words and only accept the string if the 1 of the next three words are found in the group returned.

```
import re
strings = ['Large pizza with Pepperoni','Pepperoni pizza size Large','Large but not food','cheese no size','small mac cheese']
for s in strings:
    f1 = re.findall(r'(.{0,25}\b(small|medium|large)\b.{0,25})',s, re.IGNORECASE)
    if f1:
        f2 = re.findall(r'(.{0,25}\b(cheese|pepperoni|sausage)\b.{0,25})',f1[0][0], re.IGNORECASE)
        if f2:
            print('<',s,'> contains <',f1[0][1],'> and <',f2[0][1],'>')
```

output

```
< Large pizza with Pepperoni > contains < Large > and < Pepperoni >
< Pepperoni pizza size Large > contains < Large > and < Pepperoni >
< small mac cheese > contains < small > and < cheese >
```

Comment: I like this format as it keeps the group of words separate!

Comment: I was doing this and trying to figure out how to add the near word indicator {0,6}? to the if x and y 

x = re.findall
y = re.findall
if x and y:
  print("response")

Comment: I was looking in the 25 characters because of the requirement of having the words near to one another.

Comment: If I wanted to match any word first in f1 without using near, then if word is present in f1, find a word in f2 (using near to found word in f1) I would delete the {0,25} from f1 and that should work?

Comment: please accept the answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

We can use 2 regex patterns with `|` which means OR. Can therefore look for our words in either order.
I have allowed for the first letter of each word to be upper or lower case and for there to be 1 or 2 words between the key words. This makes for a long pattern.

```
(\b([Ss]mall|[Mm]edium|[Ll]arge)\b(\W+\w{1,10}){0,2}(\W+)\b([Cc]heese|[Pp]epperoni|[Ss]ausage)\b)|(\b([Cc]heese|[Pp]epperoni|[Ss]ausage)\b(\W+\w{1,10}){0,2}(\W+)\b([Ss]mall|[Mm]edium|[Ll]arge)\b)
```

Comment: That works though I was trying to stay away from multiple inputs, and I'm finding that it's the only way. 

I'm using a similar aproch basically like this
re.findall(r"\b(small|medium|large|cheese|pepperoni|sausage)(?:\W+\w+){0,6}?\W+(small|medium|large|cheese|pepperoni|sausage)\b", txt, re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: Your pattern will accept `chese and sausage` or `large and small` which I don't think that you want

Comment: I need any two words matched in any order (I guess pizza is a bad example as large and small don't make sense but in my use case I need any of the words to match)